# How do I make a floor plan with specific dimensions?

Tags: modeling

This is my very first time of using blender. I've tried several tutorials but can't find anything that tells me how to do the very basic thing i want to do.

I simply want to draw a floor plan for a room which is 13 feet by 11 feet and make it 3d so that ultimately i can play with where things go in that room.

Can anyone take me through the steps needed to do this?

I will be so grateful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Measureit addon should be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0jCdCoaRvs  I use it a lot.

Answer (score 6):

First delete the cube and add a plane. Then go to the Scene panel and set units to Imperial

[image]

Then go to the Properties panel and enter 13 feet for x and 11 feet for y value like below

[image]

Make sure apply the object scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> so further transformations don't get distorted

Comment: to make it 3D you need to specify the z dimension. If you need any help in your first steps in Blender I can advise http://gryllus.net/Blender/VideoTutorials/AllVideoTutorials.html

Comment: Don't forget to apply transforms on the object (ctrl + A) to avoid somes issues.

Answer (score 5):

1. I'd start by adding a new plane object
2. In the 3D View *Properties Shelf* You can manually set it's size to
   the required dimensions of 13 x 11.
3. Make sure apply the object scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> so further transformations don't get distorted
4. Enter edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>
5. Extrude in Z direction with <kbd>E</kbd> the height of the room
6. Select all faces and flip normals so they point inwards with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

If you have the *Backface Culling* option enabled in the 3D view you can then benefit from having the walls invisible when seen from outside, never obstructing your view while working

[image: Plan]

Comment: Missed the step of setting units to imperial or metric but other than that a lot of good tips.